# css overflow auto with fixed grid menu not working

Tags: css, grid-layout, css-grid

Hi I'm working on a challenge which i'm implementing using CSS grid.

My only last problem is that I need the top most menu which is fixed width at 520px and fixed position to be scrollable on smaller devices on the horizontal axis please advise?

For some reason overflow-x:auto; does not appear to work in this case....

```
<!--html-->
<main>
    <div class="main-menu-container">
        <ul class="main-menu">
            <li class="main-menu__item"><a href="#" class="main-menu__link js-display-grid-items" >ALL</a></li>
            <li class="main-menu__item"><a href="#" class="main-menu__link js-display-grid-items" data-griditem="a">A</a></li>
            <li class="main-menu__item"><a href="#" class="main-menu__link js-display-grid-items" data-griditem="b">B</a></li>
            <li class="main-menu__item"><a href="#" class="main-menu__link js-display-grid-items"data-griditem="c">C</a></li>
            <li class="main-menu__item"><a href="#" class="main-menu__link js-display-grid-items" data-griditem="d">D</a></li>
            <li class="main-menu__item"><a href="#" class="main-menu__link js-display-grid-items" data-griditem="e">E</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <section class="main-grid">
        <article class="main-grid__item main-grid__item--type-a is-visible">A</article>
        <article class="main-grid__item main-grid__item--type-c is-visible">C</article>
        <article class="main-grid__item main-grid__item--type-b is-visible">B</article>
        <article class="main-grid__item main-grid__item--type-e is-visible">E</article>
        <article class="main-grid__item main-grid__item--type-b is-visible">B</article>
        <article class="main-grid__item main-grid__item--type-d is-visible">D</article>
        <article class="main-grid__item main-grid__item--type-a is-visible">A</article>
        <article class="main-grid__item main-grid__item--type-b is-visible">B</article>
        <article class="main-grid__item main-grid__item--type-c is-visible">C</article>
        <article class="main-grid__item main-grid__item--type-d is-visible">D</article>
        <article class="main-grid__item main-grid__item--type-a is-visible">A</article>
        <article class="main-grid__item main-grid__item--type-e is-visible">E</article>
    </section>
</main>
<script src="js/site.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

CSS:

```
body {
padding: 0;
margin:0;
 }

main {
 max-width: 940px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande',   'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
 position: relative;
 padding: 0 15px;
  box-sizing:border-box;

  }
.main-menu-container {
position: fixed;
width: 910px;
top:0;
float:left;
height: 40px;

 }
.main-menu {
 display: grid;
 list-style: none;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
grid-gap: 20px;
padding: 0;
overflow-x: auto;
margin:0;
padding: 1em 0;
background: #fff;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;


 }

.main-menu__link {
display: block;
text-align: center;
padding:0.4em;
background-color: #9A9B9E;
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;

 }
```

https://codepen.io/angusgrant/pen/Xqzrry

Answer (score 1):

In your demo, you have the top most menu (`.main-menu`) set to `width: 910px`.

```
.main-menu {
    display: grid;
    list-style: none;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 20px;
    padding: 0;
    position: static;
    overflow-x: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em 0;
    background: #fff;
    width: 910px;     <----------
    height: 100%;
}
```

You have the parent container of this menu (`.main-menu-container`) also set to `width: 910px`.

```
.main-menu-container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 910px;     <----------
    top: 0;
    left: 15px;
}
```

Since they're both the same width at all times, there's no possibility for an overflow, regardless of screen size.

To allow for an overflow condition, make this adjustment to the parent:

```
.main-menu-container {
    position: absolute;
    /* width: 910px; */
    top: 0;
    left: 15px;
    width: 100%;       /* new */
    overflow-x: auto;  /* new */
}
```

[**revised codepen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KRyBpJ)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the element with class ".main-menu-container" to change the width in responsive, it does not depends of main since it is fixed. Also you need to set width to the "li" elements because they are adapting to the parent width and only in lower width spaces they are generating the auto scroll. Regards,